# Get Microphone Input Level Naudio

Tags: c#, audio-recording, naudio

I've been looking for a simple way to determine the volume/level of sound being inputted into the microphone, as soon as the data is available. I've not been able to find a simple answer.
Is there no simple way to do this, or am I just missing it?

Answer (score 3):

What I've been using for a peak meter (a progress bar) is the following, passing in the device from my IWaveIn.DataAvailable

```
MMDevice.AudioMeterInformation.MasterPeakValue * 100
```